# Dojo: Setting contentpane to display .php file

Tags: javascript, dojo, digit

I am probably doing something very wrong and noobish but I can't seem to figure this out.  I have a button that, when pressed, I want to set a different contentpane to run and display a .php file.  The following does nothing when I press the button:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(
        function() {
            dojo.connect(dojo.byId("mainPanel"), "onclick", callRecordsPressed);
});

function callRecordsPressed() {
       digit.byId("mainPanel").setContent('modules/content_panes/callrecords.php'); 
}
```

I have also tried running a get but this doesn't do anything either:

```
        function callRecordsPressed() {
            digit.byId("mainPanel").setContent(alert(dojo.xhrGet({
                url: 'modules/content_panes/callrecords.php',
                load: callRecordsCallBack,
                error: callRecordsError
            })));

        }

        // Function that will be called when the find user button is pressed
        function callRecordsCallBack(data, ioArgs){
        }

        function callRecordsError(data, ioArgs){
            alert('Error when attempting load call records!');
        }
```

Where I define the content pane:

```
        <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
             data-dojo-props="region: 'center'" id="mainPanel" >

            This is the right pane

        </div>
```

I have also tried setHref(..) and that didn't seem to have an effect either. Is there a set way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: don't know much about dojo, so if you find my question silly, ignore it...is any xhr request seen in the firebug/developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your content pane has really been created, this si what you are doing wrong

function callRecordsPressed() {
            digit.byId("callRecordsButton").setContent(alert(dojo.xhrGet({
                url: 'modules/content_panes/callrecords.php',
                load: callRecordsCallBack,
                error: callRecordsError
            })));

```
    }
```

should look likt this:

```
function callRecordsPressed() {
        digit.byId("callRecordsButton").set('href', 'modules/content_panes/callrecords.php');
    }
```

Comment: You were right but I also had a problem that I was saying "digit" instead of "dijit"  Accepting your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: sorry for that, i just copied from your question and modified on a hurry